# VS12, VB.NET, prerequisite check 4.5

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, frameworks, .net-3.5, installation

I'm trying to build a project for .NET Framework 3.5.

I have the following settings set:

```
Application> Target framework> .NET Framework 3.5
Compile> Prefer 32-bit (greyed out)
```

.vbproj file
    v3.5

I'm sure I've found everything that I need to set, but when I publish and try to install on the 3.5 machine, I get the error:

```
Unable to satisfy all the prerequisites for <project>. Setup cannot continue until all
system components have been successfully installed.
```

Details:

```
Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)
failed with the following error message:
"Installation of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating
system." etc...
```

What else do I have to change to get the correct Prerequisites?

Comment: You cannot install .NET 4.5 on Windows XP.  Why your installer is asking for it is not obvious from the question.  Click the Prerequisites button and verify the selections.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see its VS12.

Comment: So, you are trying to use 3.5 and its installing 4.5? Is that your problem? or do you want to use 4.5 instead?

Comment: No, to most of that. I'm developing on Windows 8 VS12 (Express) VB.NET.  I'm trying to install on XP .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Thank you Hans for the "Prerequisites button" tip. I'd missed that one.